# Undefined method error for class in Rails method called in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails have gotten rather rusty and I'm driving myself crazy trying to figure out something that is probably so basic I can't see the forest for the trees.

I have a form that goes to the `create` action of my controller. When I save I need to also update some items from another table. I want to wrap it all in a transaction. I thought the preference was to put the transaction in the model. When I do that and try to call the `create` action it errors out telling me that there is no method for that class.

equip_swaps_controller.rb

```
 def create
   respond_to do |format|
     @equip_swap = EquipSwap.new(equip_swap_params)
     if @equip_swap.trans_equip_and_save
       format.html { redirect_to @equip_swap, notice: 'Equipment transfer was successfully created.' }
     else
       format.html { render action: 'failure' }
     end
   end
 end
```

Model equip_swap.rb

```
def self.trans_equip_and_save
  EquipSwap.transaction do
    Tool.transfer_equipment(self.to_vehicle, self.items_moved)
    self.save
  end
end
```

Tool model with needed method

```
def transfer_equipment(location,ids)
  ids.each do |id|
    Tool.find(id).update(location: location)
  end
end
```

I thought that calling the class method would allow it to execute that method on my instance of the `EquipSwap` instance `@equip_swap`. When I try to submit the form and create the new record it tells me that there is no `trans_equip_and_save` method for `Class....`. There is something obvious that I'm missing. Help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Method start with `self` its call class method and and without `self` its call instance method, let me give example

```
Class method
def self.class_method
  # do some stuff
end

Instance method
def instance_method
  # do some stuff 
en
```

Call class method using

```
ModelName.class_method
```

Call instance method using

```
@instance_variable.instance_method
```

In your code change your method to instance method

```
def trans_equip_and_save
 EquipSwap.transaction do
  Tool.transfer_equipment(self.to_vehicle, self.items_moved)
  self.save
 end
end
```

And now call this method using instance variable `@equip_swap.trans_equip_and_save`

**Edit:**

If you are calling transfer_equipment using model name then add `self` before method name, I mean make it class method like following

```
def self.transfer_equipment(location,ids)
  ids.each do |id|
    Tool.find(id).update(location: location)
  end
end
```

Comment: I get an new error `undefined method `transfer_equipment' for #<Class:0x007ff28ff9af18>` from the line `Tool.transfer_equipment(self.to_vehicle, self.items_moved)`. Do I have to change the `self` in those to explicitly call the instance?

Comment: Change it to `def self.transfer_equipment(location,ids)`

Answer (score 2):

You have two things to notice here,

First of all there are two different methods, **`class methods`** and **`instance methods`**.

**Class methods:** Class methods are defined directly on a class and they are defined using `def self.method`.

Usage: `Class.method`

**Instance methods:** Instance methods are defined on an `object` of a `class` and they are defined **without self**.

Usage: `object = Class.new(),  def method ==> object.method`

So, in your case, there will be two changes,

1) you called, `@equip_swap.trans_equip_and_save`.

Since, `@equip_swap` is an object, according to second point you shold have an Since, `@equip_swap` is an object, according to second point you shold **have an instance method without self.**.

```
def trans_equip_and_save
  EquipSwap.transaction do
    Tool.transfer_equipment(self.to_vehicle, self.items_moved)
    self.save
  end
end
```

2) `Tool.transfer_equipment`, this is called with `class name`. So, according to first point it **should be called with self**.

```
def self.transfer_equipment(location,ids)
  ids.each do |id|
    Tool.find(id).update(location: location)
  end
end
```

Comment: @Beartech, pls check my answer, you have 2 changes to make. Added explanation.